# Prompting user to search for something from database using python, flask, Sqlalchemy, and HTML

Tags: python, html, flask, sqlalchemy, pythonanywhere

So I am trying to prompt the user to enter something on the web app that searches my database and returns the row onto the table on the webpage. However, I am not sure where I am messing up. I think it is in my return on flask_app.py but not sure what to make it. Any advice? I am running this off of pythonanywhere. It provides an error when I enter something into the search bar. The error tell me that the return redirect(url_for('patient_info_page'), query=search) is incorrect. When I first pull up the page, the table of the database pulls up. but I am trying to allow the user to search the db by mrn.
The exact error is below my code.

**flask_app.py**

```
class patient_ID(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "patient_ID"

    incounter_types = [('inpatient', 'inpatient'),
                   ('outpatient', 'outpatient')
                   ]

    lname = db.Column(db.String(128))
    fname = db.Column(db.String(128))
    ssn = db.Column(db.String(9),nullable=False)
    mrn = db.Column(db.String(8),primary_key=True,nullable=False)
    age = db.Column(db.String(3))
    sex = db.Column(db.String(6))
    incounter_type = db.Column(db.String(128))
    provider_lname = db.Column(db.String(128))
    provider_fname = db.Column(db.String(128))
    admin_date = db.Column(db.String(128))
    admin_time = db.Column(db.String(128))
    location_hospital = db.Column(db.String(128))
    location_floor = db.Column(db.String(3))
    location_room = db.Column(db.String(10))
    location_bed = db.Column(db.String(1))    

@app.route("/Patient_Info/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def patient_info_page():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("ID.html", query=patient_ID.query.all())

    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    smrn = request.form["mrns"]
    search = db.session.query(patient_ID).filter_by(mrn = smrn).all()

    return redirect(url_for('patient_info_page'), query=search)
```

**ID.html**

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
<div id="tfheader">
    <form id="tfnewsearch" method="POST" action=".">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mrns" size="21" maxlength="8" placeholder="Enter Patient MRN"><input type="submit" value="search" class="tfbutton">
    </form>
<div class="tfclear"></div>
</div>
{% endif %}    



<table style="margin-left: 20px;">
<!-- Table headers -->
    <th>
        <tr style="color: black; ">

        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>SSN</th>
        <th>MRN</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Sex</th>
        <th>Incounter Type</th>
        <th>Provider Last Name</th>
        <th>Provider First Name</th>
        <th>Admin Date</th>
        <th>Admin Time</th>
        <th>Hospital</th>
        <th>Floor</th>
        <th>Room</th>
        <th>Bed</th>

        </tr>
    </th>


    {%for patient_id in query%}
    <tr>
    <td>
        {{patient_id.lname}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{patient_id.fname}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{patient_id.ssn}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{patient_id.mrn}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{patient_id.age}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{patient_id.sex}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{patient_id.incounter_type}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{patient_id.provider_lname}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{patient_id.provider_fname}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{patient_id.admin_date}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{patient_id.admin_time}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{patient_id.location_hospital}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{patient_id.location_floor}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{patient_id.location_room}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{patient_id.location_bed}}
    </td>
    </tr>
    {%endfor%}

</table>
```

**Error**

```sh
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,153: Error running WSGI application
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,157: TypeError: redirect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'query'
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,157:   File "/home/tomjjoy123/.virtualenvs/flask-tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,158:     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,158: 
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,158:   File "/home/tomjjoy123/.virtualenvs/flask-tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,158:     response = self.handle_exception(e)
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,158: 
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,158:   File "/home/tomjjoy123/.virtualenvs/flask-tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,158:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,158: 
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,158:   File "/home/tomjjoy123/.virtualenvs/flask-tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,159:     raise value
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,159: 
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,159:   File "/home/tomjjoy123/.virtualenvs/flask-tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,159:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,159: 
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,159:   File "/home/tomjjoy123/.virtualenvs/flask-tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,159:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,159: 
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,159:   File "/home/tomjjoy123/.virtualenvs/flask-tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,160:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,160: 
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,160:   File "/home/tomjjoy123/.virtualenvs/flask-tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,160:     raise value
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,160: 
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,160:   File "/home/tomjjoy123/.virtualenvs/flask-tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,160:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,160: 
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,161:   File "/home/tomjjoy123/.virtualenvs/flask-tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,161:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,161: 
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,161:   File "/home/tomjjoy123/.virtualenvs/flask-tutorial/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 261, in decorated_view
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,161:     return func(*args, **kwargs)
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,161: 
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,161:   File "/home/tomjjoy123/mysite/flask_app.py", line 186, in patient_info_page
    2019-11-09 01:05:15,161:     return redirect(url_for('patient_info_page'), query=search)
```

Comment: Hi, hopefully we can help you out but you'll need to provide more info. What are we looking for exactly? Does this code generate an error, or not behave the way you expect?

Comment: it provides an error when I enter something into the search bar. The error tell me that the return redirect(url_for('patient_info_page'), query=search) is incorrect. When  I first pull up the page, the table of the database pulls up. but I am trying to allow the user to search the db by mrn.

Comment: Please update your question with the full Traceback of the error.

Comment: The `query` keyword arg belongs to `url_for` not `redirect`. Change `return redirect(url_for('patient_info_page'), query=search)` to `return redirect(url_for('patient_info_page', query=search))`